# Any local browsers which pretend to be mobile?

Tags: mobile, browser

I'm currently developing a mobile site and I'm finding it very clunky to work with a browser through an emulator.

Is there any way I can make a browser (which runs on OSX) "pretend" it is a mobile browser so that I can get mobile html back from the site I'm guessing things like inspect in chrome or firebug on firefox?

NOTE: I *really* wish I could have accepted all of the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can change the User-Agent of the browser and then, the server will send you, if a mobile version is available - this one!
Like stylesheets etc.

There is a nice addon for firefox called ["User Agent Switcher"](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher/)

Answer (score 1):

For Safari;

In the normal Mac OS X Safari, go to Preferences/Advanced and check "Show develop menu in menu bar". A menu called "Develop" will show up with a sub menu called "User Agent". In that you can choose to send user agent strings for - for example - iPhone and iPad.

The develop menu also has a "Web inspector" which while not as powerful as FireBug is pretty good for inspecting the results.